# JQuery UI - Accordion - Change CSS based on bound data in MVC3

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using a jQueryUI Accordion on a page that is working fine but I would like to set the color of the header based on the data that I am displaying.

Basically, if a property on my Model data is true (eg HasErrors == true) I would like the header to display in red otherwise for them to display using the CSS theme (blue and green).

I am populating the accordion as follows:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion(
    {
        collapsible:true,
        autoHeight:false,
        active:'none'
    });
});
</script>

<div id="accordion">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<h3><a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DisplayName)</a></h3>
<div>       
    @foreach (var entry in item.StatusItems)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => entry.Actions)<br/>
    }       
</div>
}
</div>
```